# Assign INT Variable From Select Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Why do I get a syntax error on the following SQL statements:

```
DECLARE @Count90Day int;

SET @Count90Day =  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN
DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  AND Active ='Y'
```

I am trying to assign the number of rows returned from my Select statement to the variable @Count90Day.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need parentheses around the subquery:

```
DECLARE @Count90Day int;

SET @Count90Day =  (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM Employee
                    WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND 
                                                            DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  AND
                          Active ='Y'
                   );
```

You can also write this without the `set` as:

```
DECLARE @Count90Day int;

SELECT @Count90Day =  COUNT(*)
FROM Employee
WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE()) AND
      Active ='Y';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign it within the `SELECT`, like so:

```
DECLARE @Count90Day int;

SELECT @Count90Day = COUNT(*) 
FROM Employee 
WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN
DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  AND Active ='Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign SQL variables in a `SELECT` like that, you can do:

```
SELECT @Count90Day = COUNT(*) 
FROM Employee WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN
DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  AND Active ='Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
DECLARE @Count90Day int;

SELECT @Count90Day = COUNT(*) FROM Employee WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN
DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  AND Active ='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variable in `DECLARE` statement, just use round brackets around request.

```
DECLARE @Count90Day as int = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM Employee 
                              WHERE DateAdd(day,30,StartDate) BETWEEN 
                                    DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND
                                    DATEADD(day,10,GETDATE())  
                              AND Active ='Y')
```